# How should I use sshj to connect with ssh, which makes me very confused

Tags: java, ssh, sshj

Although there are examples in sshj's github, I don’t understand what I’m doing. I use the following code to try to connect to my host, and that’s it

```
 @Test
    public void sshTest() throws IOException {
        SSHClient client = new SSHClient();
        String username = "username";
        File privateKey = new File("D:\\SSH\\remote_new");
        client.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier());
        client.connect("myMostIp", 22);
        KeyProvider keys = client.loadKeys(privateKey.getPath());
        client.authPublickey(username, keys);
        client.close();
    }
```

The result of running is like this

```
net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.UserAuthException: Exhausted available authentication methods


Caused by: net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.UserAuthException: Problem getting public key from PKCS8KeyFile{resource=[PrivateKeyFileResource] D:\SSH\matcloud_new}

    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unrecognised object: OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser.readObject(Unknown Source)
    ... 71 more
```

Format of the key file

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
XXXXXXXXX
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I don't know what to do, jsch does not support key files in this format

Comment: What version of sshj? According to the README on github, sshj (which is different from jsch, even though both implement SSH) supports OpenSSH-newformat files for Ed25519 since 0.19.0 2016-11-25 and other keytypes since 0.27.0 2019-01-24

Comment: I use the latest version 0.10.0, but the problem is that when I use sshj, I can’t even log in with a password.

Comment: 0.10.0 is not anywhere near the latest version, it is from 2014. If the host allows password auth (not all do) to use it you need to call one of the `.authPassword()` methods.

Comment: So what is the latest version? When using jsch, you can normally connect through password, but not through sshj. Jsch does not support the new version of openssh key format

Comment: [The most recent release is 0.30.0](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj#user-content-release-history) although as I said before 0.27.0 (from 2 years ago) or higher should fully support OpenSSH-newfmt files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recent release is 0.30.0 although as I said before 0.27.0 (from 2 years ago) or higher should fully support OpenSSH-newfmt files. –
dave_thompson_085

use it https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj#user-content-release-history

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).